# Detect execution within Virtual-Machine, in Linux?

Tags: licensing, virtualization, virtual-machine

Need a Linux application to detect if it is executing in a Virtual-Machine (s.a. VMware ESX/ESXi, Xen, Oracle Virtualbox, Microsoft Virtual server etc.) Based on the outcome of this detection, some software licensing rules need to be enforced.

I am aware that there are some commercial software libraries/frameworks meant for licensing, that can perform such detection, but we need to roll our own due to several reasons.

What are some of the ways and means to achieve such detection ?

Comment: Detecting each type of hypervisor will require different detection methods. These detection methods typiclly take advantage of implementation details, and so may require maintenance in the future, and testing on all new releases of all hypervisors. Personally, I would not try and roll my own implementation.

Comment: ...but here's a good start for [VMWare and Virtual PC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9823/Detect-if-your-program-is-running-inside-a-Virtual). This article is a bit [more generic and theory-based](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/10/27/Can-Operating-Systems-tell-if-they_2700_re-running-in-a-Virtual-Machine_3F00_.aspx) so gives some useful background information.

Comment: Thank you @RB. It is not that we've not explored COTS options for licensing. We did, but we could not work out a source-code sale deal. We need access to source-code, for our product to pass some of the regulatory conformance requirements. Of course, that is just one, but key reason requiring us to roll our own.

Answer (score 1):

For modern hardware-accelerated (VT-x) hypervisors (VMware, VirtualBox, KVM/QEmu), they all set the "hypervisor" CPUID bit, which is quite simple to read from Linux.
Open the file /proc/cpuinfo, and look for "hypervisor" in the flags line.

It's not 100% though. Software based hypervisors (Bochs, etc) will not set it, and the bit is not enforced, so one could modify QEmu to not set the bit for instance. But, it might be enough for your uses.

Comment: To my knowledge VirtualBox do not set the hypervisor bit.

Here is a reference to Oracle doc: 
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12731